# Printing Job Queue Grid display

Tags: filter, grid, printing

I'm building a Printing Job Queue Grid Layout which contains 9 columns( Name, Status, Owner, Duration, Material 1, Material 2, Material 3, Material 4, print mode... (relevant for the current printing statuses). Besides this, my users need to view a "History" view, which allows them to resume previous jobs.

So far, I have added a toggle button which will allow them to switch to "history mode" and and change the grid's display (with the same columns).

I need another solution which will allow my users to compare current jobs with old jobs (time and material consumed), additional to the toggle.

I'm thinking about filtering but i'm not sure it will provide an added value.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add *time of print* as one of your columns, and make each column sortable. Also I would add a checkbox with the label *view printed jobs* or *view print history*. The display of printed history rows would have a different, more sublime color to distinct from actual jobs. That way the history jobs could be easily recognized even if columns were sorted by name rather than printed time.

[image: Print Queue]

Comment: +1 I think that is a more elegant solution than filtering because it only needs the user to sort and scan the data that's already there rather than decide what actual criteria/value it is that they might need to filter by. Having said that, it might be useful to be able to specify only jobs less than say a week or whatever period of time is relevant. Also the 'resume job' needs to be in there too.

Comment: Thanks @RogerAttrill - I think you're right on the time filter. A *print history* can go several years back, and we'd like to have the option to not show too old data.